# YajraDatatables in Livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, yajra-datatable

I am using YajraDatatables in the controller and it's working fine,
Below is the controller function, and it give me output in table,

```
class EodBhavDataController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index(EodBhavDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render('pages/apps.eodbhavdata.list');
    }
}
```

and the same can be viewed in the blade below,

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    {{ $dataTable->table() }}
</div>
```

Now what I did in the Livewire component is below, I am passing component property to YajraDatatables `EodBhavDataTable` and getting `$dataTable` as query output.

```
//Livewire component file.

class Trades extends Component
{
    public $property;
    public $dataTable;

    public function mount($property)
    {
        $this->property = $property;
    }

    public function render(EodBhavDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        $this->dataTable = $this->property;
        $outputTable = $dataTable->render('pages/apps.eodbhavdata.list');
        
        return view('livewire.symbol.trades', ['table' => $outputTable]);
    }
}
```

```
//livewire.symbol.trades file.

<div class="table-responsive">
    {{ $table->table() }}
</div>
```

Now I want to output the same table via the Livewire blade, but it is not showing table output but shows an error `Call to a member function table() on string`

So the question is, how do we pass the YajraDatables render table via the Livewire component?